# Where can I practice making AJAX calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm learning to make AJAX calls with jQuery and rendering the data with template engines like Mustache, Handlebars.js, and JSRender.

Is there a website or web service I can use to practice making AJAX calls and rendering them in HTML? Because of cross-domain scripting, I'm guessing there isn't a public data storage I can practice making calls with. Does a web service like this exist?

Comment: The best place to practice is 127.0.0.1...

Comment: Why not just make a dummy service that returns test data?  Surely that'll make your learning easier than trying to integrate with a public web service.  To say nothing of the fact that, as you alluded to, said service would have to support CORS to get around the cross domain issue

Comment: there's no place like 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Juhana unfortunately i'm just a front-end developer who has no idea how to make a dummy service or dummy data to call from.

Comment: I agree with @Juhana, but [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) allows testing of AJAX requests.

Comment: @Soup - you could look at Amazon's product advertising API, but you'll have to confirm that they have CORS in place.  And that they can return JSON, which I don't think they do.  Not sure you're going to get a good answer on this one.

Comment: You don't even need to install any server software. Just make a HTML page on your computer, open it in a browser and voilá.

Comment: see: http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) is actually a really good place to do this. You can make JSFiddle "[echo](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)" html or JSON that you want to get back:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(
            { hello: "world" }
        )
    },
    success: function (data) {
        /* populate a template, etc. */
    }
});
```

You can also add external resources (like a templating plugin). [**Here's an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXhTC/) using mustache.js from [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com).

Comment: okay, that's pretty awesome. how do i use a template engine with jsfiddle?

Comment: @Rocket: Thanks for the link, I've updated my answer to include it.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `dataType: 'json'` to this.

Comment: @Soup: See the last example, it's using mustache.js